# Add text side by side in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add two paragraphs by side above the email and date inputs. It's supposed to tell you what each form is for. But I can't get paragraph age on the same line as name paragraph.

I tried using `<br>` to make the text go above the input but it didn't work so well.

```css
body {}

input[type='name'] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  Margin-top: 7px;
}

input[type='date'] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 170px;
}

#emailcheck {}

.checkboxes label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.checkboxes input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkboxes label span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form {
  padding: 10px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form" style="width:400px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; border:1px solid #000;">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <p>NAME</p><br>
    <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="First and Last names" required/>
    <p>AGE</p>
    <input type="date" id="date" required/>
    <div class="checkboxes">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="emailcheck" name="emailcheck" value="yes"> <span>Receive emails?</span></label><br>
      <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your hard-coded width of 400px is not sufficient to allow everything onto the same line.

Comment: No, I don't want anything on the same line I just want the Name and Age on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.form {
  padding: 10px;
  width:400px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

form > div {
  display: flex;
}

input[type='name'] {
  width: 170px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 7px 5px 5px 0;
}

input[type='date'] {
  width: 170px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 7px 5px 5px 0;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>NAME</label>
        <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="First and Last names" required/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>AGE</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes">
      <input type="checkbox" id="emailcheck" name="emailcheck" value="yes" />
      <label>Receive emails?</label>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```